# Writing Assembly and C in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2012

I have seen a lot of talk about this but I can't get it to work. Maybe the information is outdated or I might have done something wrong. But, is it possible to write and compile Assembly and C code in Visual Studio?

Are there basic project templates available for these languages, I mean, in the same way that there are VB, C++ and C# project templates for creating new projects?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I also have all of the Visual Studio Express Editions installed.

Is it possible to write assembly and/or C code from within a normal C++ project?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I want to learn more low level languages. I feel like I would be able to better understand a lot of things if I learn what is actually happening at a much lower level.

Comment: Do you mean inline assembly, i.e. [__asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx), or whole object files and functions in assembly? C: yes, you just need to prefix the function defs with `extern "C"` when you include them from C++ code.

Comment: Go to "Build Customizations", enable "masm", make some .asm files.. at least, that used to be the routine on VS2010.

Comment: Regarding assembler: Are [intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) an option? They have been pushed by Microsoft as a successor to the inline assembler functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing to be aware of is that, as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk4z78b.aspx), you can't use inline assembly when compiling for x64.

Visual Studio also includes the MASM assembler in both `ml.exe` (32-bit) and `ml64.exe`. [This](http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm) may be of some assistance with getting started on their use.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, VS does not include a standalone assembler. You can write inline assembly in your C or C++ source code, but only for x86 targets. For anything beyond inline assembly you'll need to use a separate assembler. You can of course link the object files produced by an assembler into your MSVC project.

As for C, the MS compiler will compile code that broadly follows the C89 standard. But MS have stated repeatedly that they will not update their C compiler to newer standards. If what MS support is enough you just include files with a .c extension in your project and compile. Otherwise, if what MS support is not sufficient for you, then you are looking at external compilers.

**Update**

I stand corrected. Visual Studio does indeed ship with the standalone Microsoft assembler MASM.

Comment: Actually, Visual Studio does include the MASM assembler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Just to add another tidbit: you can also get Masm free in the DDK (driver developer kit) The version of MASM included in it will assemble MMX and SSE instructions (the freely downloadable Masm doesn't)

Comment: @enhzflep - that's confusing (and news to me). Which version do you say assembles SSE and which doesn't? I seem to remember having assembled SSE-containing code with both DDK and VS versions (but I am not sure about which MASM versions now).

Comment: @PhiS - The version of Masm I've tried to do SSE stuff with was "Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved." This is the (very old) one that comes in the free distribution, Masm32, as found here: http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm.  I've just realized the source of the confusion - I'd intended to say "the freely downloadable *standalone* masm*32*" doesn't"  I'm sure the one that comes with VS express does, not sure - no VS express here. Sorry for the confusion. :blush:

Comment: @enhzflep The latest VS comes with ml v11 and it would be astounding if it did not support SSE

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks for the clarification. ml v10 from vs2010 also supports SSE, fwiw. :)

Comment: @enhzflep - OK, that makes sense. The "older" versions (like v.6) didn't support all the instruction sets and you sometimes also had to "enable" them first with the appropriate directives.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to implement some small things for a function, you can do this via inline assembly. If you want to write more complex functions, then you can also use an external assembler. In this case you can configure the properties of the source file to use an external command and you have to write the command line yourself, as well as specifying the source and targets.